# Minimize JSON to deserialize and persist complex POJO with JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jpa, jackson

I have a fairly complex POJO that I need to deserialize from a JSON string and persist in a MySQL database. The following is a very simplified example class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="a")
public class A{
    private Long id;
    private B b;
    private C c;
    private D d;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="b_id")
public B getB(){
    return this.b;
}

public void setB(B b){ this.b = b; }

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="c_id")
public C getC(){ 
    return this.c;
}

public void setC(C c){ this.c = c; }

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="d_id")
public D getD(){ 
    return this.d;
}

public void setD(D d){ this.d = d; }
```

Each class `B`, `C`, and `D` also have a number of fields and objects (some with even more required objects and fields) that can not be null according to the database schema, which I can't change. I can deserialize and persist this no problem, but the JSON required to do so is really massive.  I only need to persist the deserialized `A`, so I really just need the `_id` fields from `B`, `C`, and `D`.

Right now my JSON is something like:

```
{
  "id":1, 
  "b":{"id":2, ...}, 
  "c":{"id":3, ...}, 
  "d":{"id":4, ...}
}
```

where I have to fill in all the non-nullable database fields. What I would like to do is read a JSON string like:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "b_id":2,
  "c_id":3,
  "d_id":4
}
```

and just have Hibernate/JPA update those fields in the database. I think the real tricky part is that other classes/methods in my application will need the entire object hierarchy for reading from the database. The only time I can use just the `_id` fields is during the deserialization of the JSON. When this is the case, I only need to update the top-most object (`A` in my example) and some other trivial fields. In a perfect world, I can just throw some annotations on my class to solve this problem, but I haven't found anything capable of doing this.

Is this even possible? If so, can it be done with JPA/Jackson annotations?

Thanks!

Comment: You can write a custom deserializer and use `@JsonDeserialize(using = ...)`

Comment: I'm aware of custom deserializers (I use them elsewhere in my application). Could you elaborate on how this might solve my problem?

Comment: Well, when you deserialize, you have access to the `JsonParser`. And `JsonParser` can help you get the needed information (current member name, etc etc).

Comment: Do you control the incoming JSON?

Comment: @Jukka, To a degree, yes. Another development team is writing it and sending it to my application via a RESTful call. I can ask for certain fields that they may or may not be able to send to me based on an existing database schema that we can't change.

Comment: Edited for clarification of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If mapping the JSON directly to your entities is akward, I would simply make the translation from the incoming JSON string to your entities explicit via an intermediate object (call it a DTO if you will).

I also have a gut feeling that if you save associated object references (the @ManyToOnes) with only the id populated, Hibernate will in fact save the association correctly (root object here represents A):

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "b" : {
        "id" : 2
    },
    ...
}
```

Make sure you don't cascade the persist operation for the b, c etc. fields.

Comment: Oh and if you don't really need the getters and setters, consider using public fields.

Comment: "I also have a gut feeling that if you save associated object references (the @ManyToOnes) with only the id populated, Hibernate will in fact save the association correctly (root object here represents A):" Do you think this will work even if I omit the non-nullable fields specified by the schema on the @ManyToOnes?

Comment: Turns out you were right about only needing the @ManyToOne ID fields populated. I didn't even need a DTO. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should create new classes which define only this fields which you want to deserialize. For example if you want to deserialize only `ID` your class could looks like this:

```
class JsonEntity {

    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setUnknownProperties(String name, String value) {
        //do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(id);
    }
}
```

In this example annotation [`JsonAnySetter`](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureAnyGetter) do the trick. Now, you have to create some class which will be simulating your `A` class. For example:

```
class DtoA extends JsonEntity {

    private JsonEntity b;
    private JsonEntity c;
    private JsonEntity d;

    public JsonEntity getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(JsonEntity b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public JsonEntity getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(JsonEntity c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public JsonEntity getD() {
        return d;
    }

    public void setD(JsonEntity d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A [id=" + getId() + ", b=" + b + ", c=" + c + ", d=" + d + "]";
    }
}
```

Now when we have new JSON data model we can test it. For example we can parse below JSON:

```
{
  "id":1, 
  "b":{"id":2, "p1":"v1", "p2":"v2"}, 
  "c":{"id":3, "p3":"v3", "p4":"v4", "p5":"v5"}, 
  "d":{"id":4, "p6":"v6"}
}
```

Deserialization example:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
DtoA a = objectMapper.readValue(json, DtoA.class);
System.out.println(a);
```

Above program prints:

```
A [id=1, b=2, c=3, d=4]
```

Now, you have to implement `toA()` method in `DtoA` class which could look like this:

```
public A toA() {
    A a = new A(getId());
    a.setB(new B(getB().getId()));
    a.setC(new C(getC().getId()));
    a.setD(new D(getD().getId()));

    return a;
}
```

Let me know whether it works for you.